# I'm building a simple workout program app, but I want to simplify the Javascript/jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, function, for-loop

Here is my code

```
 $('#addmaxes').on('click',function(){
dlMax = $('#dlcurrentmax-input').val().trim();
ftsqMax = $('#ftsqcurrentmax-input').val().trim();
per = 95;
dlTrainingMax = (dlMax * per) / 100;
frsqTrainingMax = (ftsqMax * per) / 100;
per= 75;
var weekDl = (dlTrainingMax * per) / 100;
var rnWeekDl = Math.floor(weekDl);
per2= 60;
var weekDef = (dlTrainingMax * per2) / 100;
var rnDefWeek = Math.floor(weekDef);
var weekSq = (frsqTrainingMax * per2) / 100;
var rnWeekSq = Math.floor(weekSq);
var newDivOne = $('<div>');
var newDivTwo = $('<div>');
newDivOne.addClass('trainingProgram');
newDivTwo.addClass('trainingProgram');
newDivOne.html('<h3>Week 1');
newDivTwo.html('Deadlift (75%): 3x5 at ' + rnWeekDl + '<br/>Deficit Deadlift (60%): 8x3(90sec rest between sets) at ' + rnDefWeek + '<br/>Front Squat (60%): 3x8 at ' + rnWeekSq + '<br/>Stiff-leg deadlift: 3x8 ' + '<br/>Bent over rows: 3x8' + '<br/>Lat pulldowns:  3x12');

$('#program').append(newDivOne);
$('#program').append(newDivTwo);
});
```

so basically I copy and paste this function multiple times and change the added html that is in each function to display the workout for that week.(so each copied function represents a workout week)
One way I found to simplify the code is by creating an array of objects like this:

```
const PERCENT_FOR_MAX = 95;
var percentagesPerWeek = [
{
deadlift: 75,
frontSquat: 50,
},
{
deadlift: 80,
frontSquat: 65,
},
/// etc
];
```

and then add a for loop to my function like this:

```
$('#addmaxes').on('click',function(){
for(var i = 0; i < percentagesPerWeek.length; i++) {
dlMax = $('#dlcurrentmax-input').val().trim();
ftsqMax = $('#ftsqcurrentmax-input').val().trim();
dlTrainingMax = (dlMax * PERCENT_FOR_MAX) / 100;
frsqTrainingMax = (ftsqMax * PERCENT_FOR_MAX) / 100;
var deadliftPercent = percentagesPerWeek[i].deadlift;
var weekDl = (dlTrainingMax * deadliftPercent) / 100;
var rnWeekDl = Math.floor(weekDl);
var frontSquatPercent = percentagesPerWeek[i].frontSquat;
var weekDef = (dlTrainingMax * frontSquatPercent) / 100;
var rnDefWeek = Math.floor(weekDef);
var weekSq = (frsqTrainingMax * frontSquatPercent) / 100;
var rnWeekSq = Math.floor(weekSq);
var newDivOne = $('<div>');
var newDivTwo = $('<div>');
newDivOne.addClass('trainingProgram');
newDivTwo.addClass('trainingProgram');
newDivOne.html('<h3>Week 2</h3>');
newDivTwo.html('Deadlift ('+deadliftPercent+'%): 3x5 at ' + rnWeekDl +
  '<br/>Deficit Deadlift (65%): 8x3(90sec rest between sets) at ' + rnDefWeek +
  '<br/>Front Squat ('+frontSquatPercent+'%): 3x8 at ' + rnWeekSq +
  '<br/>Stiff-leg deadlift: 3x8 ' +
  '<br/>Bent over rows: 3x8' +
  '<br/>Lat pulldowns:  3x12'
);
$('#program').append(newDivOne);
$('#program').append(newDivTwo);
}});
```

but the problem I'm running into is that the html that is in each function is going to be the same each week, and I need it to be customized each week,because workouts change. How can I do this. I am new to web development and have only been doing this for a month. So i'm sorry if my context is not making  sense, and also this is my first time posting to this forum. Thanks in advance. :)

Answer (score 0):

If you're only beginning to learn JavaScript try to avoid using jQuery - it's a crutch you don't really need for web development on modern web browsers. Also the native browser API is more performant.

Your click handler function doesn't have to be included explicitly in the event listener. The **Separation of Concerns (SoC)** principle states that you should avoid co-locating different concerns within the design/code. This means you should separate the functions which handle the event, from the event listeners which trigger the handlers.

You should set up the handler as a named function that you pass in, like this.

```
var addMaxesHandler = function(event) {
  // handle the '#addmaxes' click event here

  // assuming you need integer values
  var dlMax = Math.parseInt(document.getElementById('dlcurrentmax-input').value, 10);
  var ftsqMax = Math.parseInt(document.getElementById('ftsqcurrentmax-input').value, 10);
  var presentationData = doTheCalculations(percentagesPerWeek, dlMax, ftsqMax);

  presentTheResults(presentationData);
};

// attach the listener to the HTML element
var el = document.getElementById('addmaxes');
el.addEventListener('click', addMaxesHandler);
```

It also means you can remove it later if you want using `removeEventListener()`. You cannot do this with the anonymous function.

Remember the **Single Responsibility Principle (SRP)**? In your case you should have your functions perform one task and one task only - don't mix the calculations with the presentation. Keep breaking the problem down into smaller pieces and compose the results together.

```
function doTheCalculations(dataArr, dl, ftsq) {

  // need a container for holding the results of calculations
  var calculationResults = [];

  // iterate through the 'percentagesPerWeek' array
  dataArr.forEach(function(values, index){
    // values is the array element e.g. { deadlift: 75, frontSquat: 50 }
    // index is the array index e.g. 0 for the first element of the array
    calculationResults.push(doTheMathsFunc(values, dl, ftsq));
  });

  return calculationResults;
}
```

I haven't implemented it, but the `doTheMathsFunc()` should perform the calculations and return an object or array containing the values to be used in the presentation. At this point you have returned another array of objects which you can used to create your HTML.

```
function presentTheResults(resultsArr) {
  // this function will iterate through the array and build the HTML

  // use DocumentFragment object for efficiency
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();

  // get some HTML content
  resultsArr.forEach(function(result, index){
    var weekFragment = getWeekHtmlBlock(result, (index + 1));
    fragment.appendChild(weekFragment);
  });

  // get a handle on the DOM container element
  var container = document.getElementById('program');

  // add the DocumentFragment to the DOM
  container.appendChild(fragment);
}
```

That function just stitches the HTML fragments together and attaches the result to the DOM. The HTML fragments are created by another function `getWeekHtmlBlock()`.

```
// build the block of HTML content for the week
function getWeekHtmlBlock(content, week) {
  // content : object containing the information
  // week : the week number
  var fragment = document.createDocumentFragment();
  // create HTML elements
  var outerDiv = document.createElement('div');
  var innerDiv = document.createElement('div');
  // add the CSS class
  outerDiv.classList.add('trainingProgram');
  // add the H3 tag : e.g. 'Week 1'
  var h3 = document.createElement('h3');
  h3.textContent = "Week " + week;
  outerDiv.appendChild(h3);
  // iterate through the 'content' object and build the HTML elements
  // these should be appended to 'innerDiv'

  // TO DO !
  innerDiv.appendChild( getInstructionsHtml(content, week) );

  // append the HTML elements
  outerDiv.appendChild(innerDiv);
  fragment.appendChild(outerDiv);
  // return the HTML
  return fragment;
}
```

Hopefully by now you get the idea - keep solving smaller pieces of the problem by using a function.

If you need to change the instructions to be presented for each week then it might be a good idea to create an array of objects containing instructions for each one. The first element of the array would contain the instructions for the first week and so on.

[Template literals/Template strings](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) are a feature of ES2015 so you should be able to take advantage of them now.
[Deconstructing assignment](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment) is also a JavaScript feature added in ES2015.

```
// example array of instructions
var weeklyInstructionsArray = [
  [`Deadlift (${deadliftPercent}%): 3x5 at ${rnWeekDl}`,
  `Deficit Deadlift (65%): 8x3 (90sec rest between sets) at ${rnDefWeek}`,
  `Front Squat (${frontSquatPercent}%): 3x8 at ${rnWeekSq}`,
  `Stiff-leg deadlift: 3x8`,
  `Bent over rows: 3x8`,
  `Lat pulldowns: 3x12`]
];

function getInstructionsHtml(data, weekNum) {

  var instructions = weeklyInstructionsArray[weekNum-1];

  // Using deconstructing assignment
  // NOTE: The variable names must match those in the template literals above
  var {deadliftPercent, rnWeekDl, rnDefWeek, frontSquatPercent, rnWeekSq} = data;

  // stitch the array of template literals together in a single text node
  var htmlContent = document.createTextNode( instructions.join('<br/>') );

  return htmlContent;

}
```

Hopefully this answer is detailed enough to show you how to go about solving the issue.